# WCF shared types in WSDL

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, namespaces

I have to use several separate webservices from the same provider. Basicly every function has its own service (wsdl). For interop every wsdl has references for shared types (ex: xs:import namespace="http://generic.type.com" />).

Adding Service Referances in VS will prefix the service namespace to these types.
Adding two services will generate two separate but identical class:

```
var context = new Service1.GenericContext();

var contex2 = new Service2.GenericContext();
```

How can I map/cast these together? I have 20+ services like this.

Tried NamespaceMappings in Reference.svcmap, but faild. I don't know what TargetNamespace and ClrNamespace to use.

ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding service references you should use svcutil.exe to generate **one** service proxy file for the endpoints all together.

All service proxy classes are then together in the same namespace you specify with the command line switch /n.

The svcutil.exe call has many parameters then. So I recommend you store it in a batch file or even more comfortable: Place the command call under Build Events in Visual Studio into "Pre-build event command line".

Here is the svcutil call for my client which puts all proxy classes together in ServiceProxy.cs. Most likely you have to modify the path to svcutil.exe and of course the service URLs:

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\svcutil.exe" /noLogo /noConfig /out:"$(ProjectDir)ServiceProxy.cs" /t:code /i /l:cs /tcv:Version35 /ser:DataContractSerializer /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /n:*,Oe.Corporate.CRMFacade.Service.Test http://localhost:3615/Client010/MasterDataService.svc http://localhost:3615/Client010/BusinessPartnerService.svc http://localhost:3615/Client010/MarketingAttrService.svc http://localhost:3615/Client010/ProductTransactionService.svc http://localhost:3615/Client010/ProductDataService.svc http://localhost:3615/Client010/ActivityManagementService.svc http://localhost:3615/Client010/PromotionService.svc
```

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention that the pre-build event will fail unless you add this to the bottom of your .csproj file right above the closing Project element:

```
<Target Name="PreBuildEvent" Condition="'$(PreBuildEvent)'!=''" DependsOnTargets="$(PreBuildEventDependsOn)">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PreBuildEvent)" ContinueOnError="true" />
</Target>
```

Comment: ty! I got this error: "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."
The services are on https. I can't find option to force accept the certificate.

Comment: Please direct your machine to trust the remote certificate by importing it into your local store. That can either be done via mmc snap-in or more convenient by just browsing with IE to the web-service and tell IE to permanently trust the certificate. This will import it into your local certification store. But you must use IE since Firefox has it's own certification store.

Comment: Tried IE and MMC, cert is listed in mmc under Trusted Root Certification Authorities, still not working.

In c# i can bypass the cert with ICertificatePolicy.

Comment: As far as I know WCF prevents you from bypassing several security rules. But what you have done sounds right to me. So I suggest you start an extra question in order to have more people looking into that special issue that is apart from your initial question. Thank you for accepting my answer! Hope it has gotten you a little bit further.

Comment: plz look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862213/svcutil-generated-code-missing-parts
ty!